# Single word request - Lose interest after doing something of interest repeatedly

Tags: meaning

Is there any awesome word for this above mentioned phrase?

EDIT: I understand, what you people are getting at, but what I want is somewhat uncommon and cool sounding, and the term should preferably not be generic. "Grow weary through monotony" is the most appropriate term I have found from the answers, but I want single word. I will wait a while for a more appropriate one, before marking one. "Bored" is too generalized.

Comment: *Sicken* might work – as in 'he sickened of the task'. Although, it doesn't imply he once found the task interesting.

Comment: Or possibly [*wearied*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wearied) *(of the task)* -  which can mean a loss of interest as well as physical tiredness.

Comment: I think *wearied* works well. Or simply *tired*.

Comment: Isn't this simply getting *bored*?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **weary**.

weary:

1. to make or become weary; fatigue or tire.
2. to make or grow impatient or dissatisfied with something (often followed by *of*): *he wearied of living in hotel rooms*; *he had wearied of teaching in state universities*.([Random-House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weary))

Alternatively, **jade** might fit the bill.

jade:

1. to tire or dull through repetition or excess
2. to become weary or dulled ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jade))

Comment: Jaded was my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

***[Monotony](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/monotony)*** may suggest the meaning you are referring to:

> - Lack of variety and interest; tedious repetition and routine.
>
>   - *The tedious monotony of his job did not deter him from being innovative.*

(ODO)

Answer (score 0):

There is "to become ['disillusioned'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disillusioned?s=t) with something

> **adjective**
>
> 1 - having lost one's ideals, illusions, or false ideas about someone or something; disenchanted
>
> www.dictionary.com

Similarly "to become ['disenchanted'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disenchanted?s=t) with something'

> **adjective**
>
> 1 -disappointed or disillusioned
>
> www.dictionary.com

Both of these do capture the meaning that something was once relished or appreciated but that is not now the case...

Answer (score 0):

Stultification

> stul·ti·fy /ˈstəltəˌfī/
>
> 1. cause to lose enthusiasm and initiative, especially as a result of a tedious or restrictive routine.

Answer (score 0):

Ennui?

> After fishing without results for 2 hours, he was overwhelmed with
> ennui and fell asleep.

Merriam Webster:

en·​nui | \ ˌän-ˈwē

Definition of ennui

: a feeling of weariness and dissatisfaction : boredom

Answer (score 0):

Why not make up a whole new word?  Like **monotonize**.  It collects *monotony* and *hypnosis* into a single word.

Example usage:

When we left him that morning, he was totally absorbed in playing *Stray*, but by late afternoon he was totally **monotonized.**